# How to obtain an element's offset (cross browser + mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I've been struggling to figure out how to get an element's offset on the page for multiple different purposes.  However, everything I've found and have been using seems to break when I go to mobile (and zoom+pan) or when I switch from Chrome to Firefox.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
$(element).offset();
```

This works great on desktop.  Works in every browser!  However, on Chrome mobile it doesn't always work.  If the page is panned to the top left and zoomed out all of the way, it works like a charm.  Things start to go wrong once you zoom in and then pan around.  The offset returned for some reason changes.

Next I tried...

```
element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

However with this solution appears to change based on if you scroll down the page (on desktop).  Even worse, the function doesn't appear to work exactly the same in Chrome as it does on Firefox mobile.

The only solution I found was in [rangeslider.js](https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js/blob/develop/dist/rangeslider.js).  They made a function that goes through the parent tree from the element all the way to the top, accumulating the offsets the entire way:

```
function getPositionFromNode(node) {
    var i = {"top":0, "left":0};
    while (node !== null) {
        i.top += node.offsetTop;
        i.left += node.offsetLeft;
        node = node.offsetParent;
    }
    return i;
};
```

Maybe I'm being picky, but this can't possibly be the only solution... can it?  This seems stupid and slow.  There has to be some kind of built-in browser feature that lets you get an element's offset.  Right?

Comment: Do you want the offset relative to document or window?

Comment: Preferably the document, but if you can provide a solution relative to the window too I may be able to find that useful in certain circumstances.

Comment: I have struggled with this quite a bit over the years in different projects. I need to say, traversing the dom really is the best solution if you aim for cross browser compatibility. It's not too slow either. Only times I've run into problem was when I call it inside a function that gets called too many times too quickly, generally a `window resize`. This problem can be fixed by implementing a delayed execution of the function to make sure it called "once every x milliseconds at most". I would be interested if anyone can offer a more efficient solution than dom traversing, but I doubt it.